# How to exclude some calls in strace?

Tags: strace

I want to trace system calls with strace. There are too many read and write, so I want to exclude them.

Here is my test:

```
strace -e trace=!read ls
```

My PC (Ubuntu 14) failed to run this command. The error message is `!open: event not found`. I have read the man carefully and I can't understand why it failed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your shell interprets `!` as a special symbol and thus fails to run the command. Use quotes:

```
strace -e 'trace=!read' ls
```

or escape with `\`:

```
strace -e trace=\!read ls
```

Comment: Is strace filter ignoring other syscall, or is the overhead the same?

Comment: The overhead will be the same as strace is still stopping the traced process for every syscall. There's work underway to change that using seccomp-bpf though (see the strace mailing list).

Comment: To ignore multiple system calls: `strace -e 'trace=!read,write' ls`